# Почему выдаёт ошибку "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Tags: c#, массивы

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int n;
        Console.WriteLine("Задайте количество эл. в массиве");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] a = new int[n, n];

        Console.WriteLine("Задайте эл. массива ");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)

            {
                Console.Write("Задайте эл. a[" + i + "] :");
                Console.Write("Задайте эл. a[" + k + "] :");

                a[i, k] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }
        Console.WriteLine("\nРезультатирующий массив:");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            for (int k = 0; i < a.Length; k++)

            {
                Console.Write("{0: 0}", a[i, k]);

            }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: где выдает? Строка какая?

Comment: почему вы используете `i < a.Length;` ? a.length это все элементы массива, то есть n*n элементов.

Answer (score 2):

`a.Length` - это суммарная длина массива по всем измерениям. То есть если вы ввели `n = 3`, то `Length` будет равно 9.

Вам нужно использовать [GetLength](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength)

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < a.GetLength(1); k++)
```

Да, и обратите внимание: во втором цикле у вас опечатка `k = 0; i <`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!